# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')

Tags: node.js, git, visual-studio, node-modules, nomachine-nx

so when I try to commit my files through VS Code GUI i get this error.

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith') at calculateDefaultProjectName (c:\Users\USername\projectname\node_modules\nx\src\command-line\run-one.js:101:31) at parseRunOneOptions (c:\Users\Username\gprojectname\node_modules\nx\src\command-line\run-one.js:56:32) at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Username\projectname\node_modules\nx\src\command-line\run-one.js:20:22) at Generator.next (<anonymous>) at fulfilled (c:\Users\Username\projectname\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:164:62) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)`

Node Version: 18

I was trying to commit my files but sadly unsuccesfuly so. The strange think is when i try to commit through VS CLI it works fine. I only get this problem when I try to commit through VS Code GitCommit GUI.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason was that the **package.json was saved in non UTF**!

Resaving the file in UTF resolved the issue.